# SSIS package not able to schedule in SQL Server agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created a SSIS package to load flat file into SQL Server table. I want to automate this process by scheduling the SSIS package in SQL Server agent (I am using SQL Server 2014). I created and scheduled the job in SQL Server; but it is not executing. I am getting the job fail message as-

> The job Failed. The job was invoked by DOMAIN\abcd.  Executed as user:
>   NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT.

The package is running perfectly when I execute it in business intelligence studio. Can anyone helped me to fix this issue. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their should be more information about the error in the job history right click on job go to "view history" then expand the "+" sign and select the first step the "Message" will give you more detail.

The error is likely due to permission to read the file.  The key to that is in the error. `NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT` this is the user that is actually executing the code so that user has to have permission to read the file.  Which if it resides on a network share that won't happen because it is a local user in which case you would have to change the execution account to a domain account with permission.  If resides on a local serer simply ensure that user has access to the file.

Comment: Thank you Matt. My package is stored in my company's the shared folder